# Using an if statement to determine the highest value

Tags: c#, if-statement

My code asks the user to enter a certain amount of students and to enter there name and score depends on how many students there are. My question is, how would I use an if statement to find out the student with the highest score. (C#)

```
class Class1
{

    public void studentCount()
    {
        int studentcount;
        int i;
        int x;
        string studentname = "";


        Console.WriteLine("Enter how many students there are: ");
        studentcount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= studentcount; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter students name: ");
                studentname = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter students score: ");
                x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you want to continue using the current structure you have you'd need to store the scores in a data structure. There are better and more efficient ways to determine the highest score however.

Comment: An if-statement is probably not very helpful here, although it can be done. However, entering the data would useless, because all data is gone away after the input loop. Find out what an array or a list is. Sort the array or list and then pick the highest item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respecting your actual code, probably this would suit you well.

```
int studentcount = 0, i = 0, x = 0, highestScore = 0;
string studentname = "", highestScoreStudentName = "";

Console.WriteLine("Enter how many students there are: ");

studentcount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
{
    for (i = 1; i <= studentcount; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter students name: ");
        studentname = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter students score: ");
        x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (x > highestScore)
        {
            highestScore = x;
            highestScoreStudentName = studentname;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would I do to display the student with the highest score?

Comment: The student name with the highest score are being stored on the `highestScoreStudentName` variable :)

Comment: What if I were to display the highest and second highest? What would I do

Answer (score 3):

Keep track of the current highest x (student's score) and if a new one that's entered is higher than the last highest, update the last highest score's variable and that student's name. You'll need to use one more variable for this to keep track of the current max score. You can always update the student's name to match the student with the max score. After the loop, you can output that student's score and name.

Comment: Of course, that's right, missed that. Will update the answer and remove that part.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this. Below are a few ways. Best would be the take advantage of OOP and create classes for what you need to do, but of course there are other ways to do what you want.

**Sticking with your current method:**

```
    public void studentCount()
    {
        string highestScoringStudent;
        int highestScore = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter how many students there are: ");
        var studentCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (var i = 0; i < studentCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter students name: ");
            var tempStudent = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter students score: ");
            var tempScore = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if(tempScore > highestScore)
            {
                highestScore = tempScore;
                highestScoringStudent = tempStudent;
            }
        }
     }
```

**With a dictionary to keep track of your students:**

```
public void StudentCount()
{
    var students = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    var count = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's Name:");
         var name = Console.ReadLine();

         Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's Score:");
         var score = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

         students.Add(name, score);
    }
    var highestStudent = students.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault()
    Console.WriteLine("{0} scored {1}", highestStudent.Key, highestStudent.Value);
}
```

**Using OOP:**

```
public class TestEntry
{
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    readonly List<TestEntry> _testEntries = new List<TestEntry>();

    public void EnterTests()
    {
        _testEntries.Clear();
        var count = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's Name:");
            var testEntry = new TestEntry();

            testEntry.StudentName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Student's Score:");
            testEntry.Score = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            _testEntries.Add(testEntry);
        }
    }

    public void PrintHighestScoringStudent()
    {
        var highestTest = _testEntries.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).FirstOrDefault();
        if (highestTest == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No tests entered.");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0} scored {1}", highestTest.StudentName, highestTest.Score);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use array [] and sort it then top most value is higher

Answer (score 0):

Everton's solution will work, but I would think that you might be interested in keeping track of all scores.  In that case, you could use an Array as suggested, but a better solution is probably to use a `SortedList`.

```
SortedList<int> students = new SortedList<int>();
...
for (int i = 0; i < studentcount; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter students name: ");
    studentname = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter students score: ");
    x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
    students.Add(x);
}
int max = students.Last; //Default sorting is low to high, 
                         //though this could be changed if 
                         //you want to look into it.
```

If you wanted to keep track of scores with respect to the student, you could use a `List<Tuple<string, int>>`, but without some finagling it would not be possible to sort it.  However, using Linq finding the max value is not difficult.

```
List<Tuple<string, int> >students = new List<Tuple<string, int> >();
...
for (int i = 0; i < studentcount; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter students name: ");
    studentname = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter students score: ");
    x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
    students.Add(studentname, x);
}
int max = students.Max(a => a.Item2).FirstorDefault();
```